# Nexus 7 App Restart Issue

Tags: android

I'm asking this because it's only happening in nexus 7 device. I had an Asus nexus 7 2013 .
Issue is when my app goes into background [clicking home button] i go back to main menu and click my app icon. It simply Restarts from Splash Screen and no other app is open in background, RAM is 1.3 GB free. 
This should be happening if system is running on low memory and kills my app while in background.
I had tested my apk in other tablets it's working fine as it should work.
But Specifically in Nexus 7 it is showing rouge behavior.

Android version is 4.4.3

Is this a generic Bug or just Specific case.

Comment: Can you post device log?

Comment: @Jayant Arora Did you figure out what was happening?